# Минимальное положительное значение из списка Python

Tags: python

Я новичок, прошу объяснить как мне из списка

```
x = [-2, 0, -5, 5, 3]
```

вытащить минимальное положительное значение (тут это 3). Я понимаю что это можно сделать с помощью функции min() и значения key, но я пока слабо разбираюсь в лямбда функциях. Покажите как реализовать пожалуйста :)

Comment: чтобы без лямбды, можно скомбинировать два ответа в один: `min(i for i in x if i > 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
min(filter(lambda val: val > 0, x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вот такой забавный *функциональный* вариант без `lambda`, хотя по сути он совпадает с ответом Кирилл Малышев:

```
x = [-2, 0, -5, 5, 3]
print(min(filter((0).__lt__, x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
data_list = [-2, 0, -5, 5, 3]

def get_min_positive_number(data: list)->int:
    result = min(i for i in data if i > 0)
    return result

 print(get_min_positive_number(data_list)) # 3
```

Comment: `int(i)` вы делаете после `i > 0`, то есть зря.

Comment: `min([...])` -> `min(...)`.

Comment: ну и `result` тут только усложняет чтение.

Comment: ну и `positive`, а не `z`))

Comment: Да конечно positive))) Всегда.

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy min([...]) -> min(...) Это вы к чему написали?

Comment: @Александр Это к тому, что `list comprehension` там лишний, квадратные скобки можно просто убрать, достаточно генераторного включения

Comment: @Александр, с квадратными скобками будет сначала вычисляться новый список, а потом искаться минимум. 2 прохода вместо одного.

Comment: Да всё верно, исправил.